# How can I get values from a json string?

Tags: c, json

Let's say I had a string that contains:

```
{"ticker":{"high":8.976,"low":8.843,"avg":8.9095,"vol":2096.78,"last":8.845,"buy":8.946,"sell":8.843,"server_time":1343686701}}
```

How would I take the numbers and put them into a separate variable?

For example :

```
int high = 8.976
int low = 8.843
/* and so on */
```

Comment: Well for a start, dont use an int to store 8.976

Comment: @mathematician1975 - He could multiply it by 1000 first

Comment: would i use long double?

Comment: @user1564244 I believe there is no need for `long double`, just `float` should be enough

Comment: @user1564244 - if you have a floating point number, you usually don't want to save it in an integer variable ;)  But that's not really your question, is it?  You're more interested in how to actually parse the data, correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 That is correct, im more interested in how to actually parse the data. the usage of "int" was just an example :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways.

"sscanf" is one alternative.

The standard string functions "strstr()", "atof()", etc are another.

I'd recommend finding a good JSON-parsing library.  For example:

- http://www.digip.org/jansson/

Comment: you are a super help, as you can see im very new to C(and programing in general)